# How to modify the request body in HttpServletRequest method using HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tried using HttpRequestWrapper but it keeps giving me stream closed exception. Below is my HttpRequestWrapper  code. I was trying to modify the request body in preHandle method. after modifying the request body I want to send it to the controller. It seems like HandlerInterceptorAdapter been called twice. In the second time it complains that the stream is closed. I've seen post related to this issue but I could not find a solution.

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
private final String body;
public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    body = stringBuilder.toString();
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
    ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
        @Override public boolean isFinished() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override public boolean isReady() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {

        }

        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }
    };
    return servletInputStream;
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}

public String getBody() {
    return this.body;
}
```

}

Comment: try changing the `isReady` method to always return true, this is a long shot but maybe it helps

Comment: You cannot modify the request in an interceptor. Also you cannot modify a request, you could wrap it like you do in a `Filter` but modifying is quite a complex operation.

Comment: I know that in Jersey we can do it. https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-filters-interceptors

Comment: @ValentinCarnu I changed isReady to return true, but it did not work. it doesn't even call isReady method.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33836552/10386912) response from InputStream to servletInputStream thread, there are some details which might be helpful